# How do I test Google Play Android subscription?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

How do I test a Google Play Android subscriptions and Google API?

1. The app is uploaded, but not published.
2. The APK is activated.
3. The subscription product id is published.
4. I tried to purchase subscription on totally unrelated phone, not my account.
5. All accounts I tested  are listed in Android Developer Console > Edit Profile
6. The BILLING_REQUEST_ITEM_TYPE is set to "subs".
7. The BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION is set to 2.
8. The app is signed and a release version, `ant release installr`.

   ```
   IGNORE THIS: When I try to purchase a subscription, it displays the subscription description, but immediately says "The item you are requesting to purchase is not available."
   ```

I cannot test the Google Android Publisher web API, https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/purchases/get

```
IGNORE THIS: It requires a user subscription token but I can't get a token without buying a subscription!
```

Ok somehow it started to work and I was able to purchase a subscription. However, there was an error in my script on the server so I was not able to save the user subscription token. Now when I try to repurchase the subscription, it says "You already own this subscription."

When I click Details, it says "Item not found." with a Retry button!

I feel like I'm the only one in the world trying to use this API!

Additionally, there is an error in the Google billing API. I do not call `mBillingService.confirmNotifications()` until after I receive a confirmation from the server that the subscription was saved, yet I see a charge/deposit in my merchant account.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed a signed version of your .apk on your test-device? In order for Google Play to acknowledge your purchase request, the .apk needs to be signed (through the usual "Export"-feature in Eclipse, for example)

Comment: Yes. I'll add that. It was a release version, `ant release installr`.

Comment: Does the Billing Service return any logcat error/info messages (which may be more detailed than "The item you are requesting...")?

Comment: When I try it from my phone, (I assume Finsky is the billing service (WTF?))
D/Finsky: [26] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.kizbit.pairfinder: Account from first account.
E/Volley: [14] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/completePurchase
W/Finsky: [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse: DisplayErrorMessage[Your order could not be processed. Please try again.]
E/Finsky: [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, message=Your order could not be processed. Please try again.

Comment: When I try from my sister's phone: Ok now it worked. Maybe it took a while after I entered her email on the list of test users? Now I have another problem. There was a script error and I could not save the purchase token. When I try to repurchase, it says "You already own this subscription." When I click Details, it says "Item not found!" I feel like I'm the only one in the world using this API!

Comment: I had the same issues. The whole item not found issue went away while the app was published. As soon as I unpublished the app this issue came back

Comment: The API will not allow you to purchase the subscription twice, if you failed to store purchase details (the purchaseToken) at the point of the successful purchase then you must use the Restore Purchases mechanism to re-retrieve these details. In general, I feel your pain with the overall subscription system, especially when it comes to testing.